# 1+0000 [main] internal.Node.run - Exception during node startup {}

Tags: corda

Getting the below error when trying to start the node  (corda.jar) whose node config file contains the public IP address of my AWS instance  instead of localhost:

> 1+0000 [main] internal.Node.run - Exception during node startup {}
>       .BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind
>       t sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
>       t sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
>       t sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
>       t sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
>       t io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:128) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
>       t io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:554) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
>       t io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1258) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
>       t io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:501) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
>       t io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:486) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
>       t io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:980) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
>       t io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:250) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
>       t io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:365) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
>       t io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
>       t io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
>       t io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
>       t io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) ~[netty-all-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
>       t java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `address` and `adminAddress` in your node's RPC settings to `0.0.0.0`, leaving the port untouched. For example:

```
rpcSettings {
    address="0.0.0.0:10010"
    adminAddress="0.0.0.0:10011"
}
```

These addresses do not need to be accessible from other nodes, as they are solely used by the node itself during start-up.